# Prepared statement returns no rows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

Brief version (without try's and catches):

```
$dbConnection = new PDO("mysql:host=$serverName;dbname=$dbName", $userName, $password, $dbOptions);
$dbStatement = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM bin_content WHERE LotId=":lot";');
dbStatement->bindParam(':' . $key, $filter->$key);
// $filter->lot contains "A32" and $key="lot",
// so I'm assuming "A32" will be filled into the statement
$dbStatement->execute(); // this is actually in a try/catch, and no exceptions are caught here
$row = $dbStatement->fetch(); // this returns false
```

As mentioned in the above code, the `fetch()` returns `false`, but if I manually query my database with the following SQL statement, a row is returned:

```
SELECT * FROM bin_content WHERE LotId="A32";
```

I'm binding a property of the `$filter` object because the queries are dynamic depending on the properties of `$filter`. Is it possible that somehow I'm not binding what I think I'm binding?

Comment: Drop the quotes around `":lot"`

Comment: You have double quotes for some odd reason and `;` inside your prepare. You need neither.

Comment: @N.B. and Sean, the reason is not really that odd..this is my first attempt at prepared statements. Noob error. :)

Comment: You guys might as well get some points out of this (and it might help a future noob). Post some answers and I'll up-vote and select.

Comment: It's a common mistake, I'm personally fine with you just fixing it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using prepared statements, don't quote what you would like to later 'inject' safely into the statement.

If you query this

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE user = 'some-user'"
```

It will literally look for users with that name, which is why it literally looks for users ":lot" when you query the database.

Instead use

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE user = :user_name"

bindParam->(':user_name', $var);

->execute ();
```

Now it will safely inject $var into the prepared statement, then you can execute it